# Laravel Dusk - Run tests & get results via code

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

I need to make a tool to Browser test my production system. I have read up all about [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk) and it seems like a perfect tool. However, I need to run tests automatically via schedule and have a dashboard with the results.

I can easily run the command `php artisan dusk` from the code using the Scheduler, however, how can I get the results? Is there a better option than simply parsing the Console Output from that command? Ideally I would have a way of getting the status of each test (whether it passed or failed) to be able to log, process and display all that information.

The Dusk documentation hasn't got any more information on running the tests programatically, it only has instructions to run via `php artisan dusk`.

Has anyone encountered this?

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/beyondcode/dusk-dashboard

Comment: @Here2Help Thank you for the link. I have seen that package, and it seems to do a lot. However, it doesn't seem to have a look of ways to hook into it (to monitor it, send notifications etc.), therefore I am looking for a way to hook into the results myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have achieved what I needed is to use the command options for dusk/phpunit.

I used `--filter=MyTestClass` to single out which test I wanted to run, and `--log-junit log.log` to log the results for that test, which I then parsed via code as well to fetch the results. This allowed me to build a fully custom dashboard that was able to run each test individually, report the results, send notifications etc.

Not the prettiest solution, but it worked well for what I needed. If anyone encounters better way to achieve that (or just use Dusk in general as a browser/scraper outside phpunit) please do post a comment/answer!

Comment: able to share your log file parsing code?

Comment: can you make it as a package? or share code!

Comment: @NeerajSharma @bilogic haven't worked on this in a while so won't be able to make a package, but parsing the log is very simple, I just used `$xml = SimpleXMLElement($path)` to read it and then it has all the useful information under `$xml->testsuite`, e.g. `$xml->testsuite['errors']` `$xml->testsuite['failures']` `$xml->testsuite['time']` and so on

Comment: Thanks @Giedrius. I appreciate your help. Let me try using SimpleXMLElement class